# Signed APK crashes with picasso,retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

While trying to generate a signed APK, android studio gave me warnings as it was not able to reference okhttp classes. I found out that it is a very common issue and has been asked several times. After reading many solutions, I added the -dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.** to my progaurd file. It, now generates the apk without any warning but crashes as soon as the app makes the first API call through retrofit.
   I know it has been asked many times, but my problem is not yet solved.

Also, I have tried using okhttp3 instead of okhttp, but still the app crashes

Here is the first API call where the app crashes,

```
     call.enqueue(new Callback<LoginResponse>() {
           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<LoginResponse> call, Response<LoginResponse> response) {
               if(response.body().getStatus().equals("success")){

               // handle login
```

and here is the log error:

```
 Exception java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

I guess, as the API call cannot be made, the response body is automatically null and thatswhy it is giving me a NullPointerException

Comment: log the crash and post

Comment: please check the edit for that

Comment: add a check before it..if(response != null && response.isSuccessfull) response.body

Comment: add this checking

Comment: tried that, control moves to else clause ( null response) , plus it is working totally fine in the debug APK, so I am assuming this has something to do with the signing of APK

Comment: then response.body().getStatus() is null ..it has nothing to do with signed apk.. test it thoroughly..

Comment: If I use the debug APK, the process works fine then why show such an issue with release apk

Comment: release apk is getting null .. may be its a different login

Comment: I checked that too , but the debug APK and release APK are using the same login API . I was wondering if there is any problem with minifyEnabled true

Comment: @Dheeraj: Any solution did you find on this? As because, I am facing the same issue in my signed APK.